# How to run FFMPEG in laravel project

Tags: laravel-5, ffmpeg, command, laravel-controller

I can run this code via cmd. And my question is how can I run this command to my laravel project locally and also to my live server?

> ffmpeg -i input1.webm -i input2.webm output.mp3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. you install the ffmpeg .exe file on your system.
2. Then you use that code in your application so,first you need to install the application of ffmpeg

Comment: Should I put that code in my Controller? Because I'm little confuse. Thanks

Comment: Do you have sample snippet?

Answer (score 0):

public function store(Request $request) {

```
    $rules =  [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'meta_title' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'video_file' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required',
    ];
    $messages = [
        'category_id.required' => 'Category field required.',
        'tags.required' => 'Tag field required',

    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules, $messages);

    $validator->sometimes('file', 'nullable|mimes:csv,xlsx|max:1024000', function ($request) {
        $messages = ['file.mimes'=>'file type must be csv or xlsx.'];
        return ($request->category_id == 2 || $request->category_id == 4);
    });
    $validator->sometimes('file', 'nullable|mimes:pdf|max:1024000', function ($request) {
        $messages = ['file.mimes'=>'file type must be pdf.'];
        return ($request->category_id == 1);
    });
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors(),'status'=>false]);
    }else {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {

            $formData = new Video();
            $formData->title = $request->title;
            $formData->user_id = Auth::id();
            $formData->description = $request->description;
            $formData->upload_date = Carbon::now();
            //$formData->meta_title = implode(",",$request->meta_title);
            $formData->meta_description =isset($formData->meta_description)?implode(",", $request->meta_description):'';
            //$formData->tags = implode(",",$request->tags);

           $formData->category_id = $request->category_id[0];

            if($request->hasFile('image_file')) {
                $uploadedFile = $request->file('image_file');
                $filename = time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
                $imagePath =  Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs(
                    'images',
                    $uploadedFile,
                    $filename
                  );
                $formData->image_file = $imagePath;
            }

             if($request->hasFile('video_file')) {
                $uploadedFile = $request->file('video_file');
                $filename = trim(time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());
                $removeSpaceFromFile = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $filename);
                $filePath =  Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs(
                    'videos',
                    $uploadedFile,
                    $removeSpaceFromFile
                  );
                $formData->video_file = $filePath;

                $video_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
                $filefullPath = asset('storage').'/'.$filePath;
                $getOutputFilePath = Mp3AndTumbnails::where('id',1)->first();
                $outputMp3File =  $getOutputFilePath->mp3_output_path;
                $outputImageFile =  $getOutputFilePath->thumbnails_path;
                // $mp3Filename = $video_id.'.mp3';
                // $imageFileName = $video_id;
                $mp3Filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '_',$request->title).'.mp3';
                $imageFileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '_',$request->title);


                $output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '. $filefullPath.' -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 '. $outputMp3File.'/'.$mp3Filename);
                $imageOutput = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$filefullPath.' -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -s 370x220 '.$outputImageFile.'/'.$imageFileName.'.jpg -hide_banner');
                $formData->mp3_file = $mp3Filename;
                $formData->image_file = 'images/'.$imageFileName.'.jpg';
                $dur = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$filefullPath." 2>&1");
                preg_match("/Duration: (.{2}):(.{2}):(.{2})/", $dur, $duration);
                if(isset($duration[1])) {

                    $hours = $duration[1];
                    $minutes = $duration[2];
                    $seconds = $duration[3];
                    $video_length = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
                    $formData->video_length = $video_length;
                }
            }
            if($request->hasFile('file')) {
                $lyricsFile = $request->file('file');
                $categoryInfo = Category::where('id',$request->category_id[0])->first();
                $filename = time().$lyricsFile->getClientOriginalName();
                $lyricsFile->move(public_path("download".'/'.$categoryInfo->name), $filename);
                $path = $filename;
                $formData->lyrics_file = $path;
            }
            $formData->save();
            foreach ($request->category_id as $key => $value) {
                $category = new VideoCategoryUpload();
                $category->video_id = $formData->id;
                $category->category_id = $value;
                $category->save();
            }
            $updateEncodeVideoId = Video::where('id',$formData->id)
                                    ->update(['base64_encode_video_id'=>base64_encode($formData->id)]);

            foreach ($request->tags as $key => $value) {
                $tagData = new TagModel();
                $tagData->user_id = Auth::id();
                $tagData->video_id = $formData->id;
                $tagData->name = $value;
                $tagData->slug_name = $value;

                $tagData->save();
            }

             foreach ($request->meta_title as $key => $value) {
                $metaTitleData = new MetaTitleModel();
                $metaTitleData->user_id = Auth::id();
                $metaTitleData->video_id = $formData->id;
                $metaTitleData->title_name = $value;
                $metaTitleData->title_slug_name = $value;

                $metaTitleData->save();
            }

            DB::commit();
            return response()->json(['status'=>true,'msg'=>'File uploaded successfully !!.']);
        }catch(\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json(['status'=>'exception','msg'=>'Something Went Wrong !!.']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check this controller in this when a video is uploaded then mp3 and banner of the video is created with this code. hope this help